# What's the maximum number of faces a convex polyhedron can have, given that it's polyhedron with all the same faces?

Tags: geometry, solid-geometry

I know there's a polyhedron named a disdyakis triacontahedron, it has 120 faces and they're all the same. Could there be a polyhedron with a larger number of faces? Can it be arbitrarily large?

Answer (score 8):

For the non-rotational [isohedra](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Isohedron.html), 120 is the upper limit.  But as I [answered here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1408056/how-many-face-we-could-make-regular-convex-polyhedron/1408071) and showed in [Some Polyhedra with Identical Triangular Faces](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/SomePolyhedraWithIdenticalTriangularFaces/), it's possible to combine antiprisms and pyramids.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The [wikipedia article for the disdyakis triacontahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disdyakis_triacontahedron) mentions that it is has the largest number of sides for any strictly convex polyhedron where all sides are congruent -- *except* for [bipyramids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipyramid) and [trapezohedra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezohedron), which are two infinite families of polyhedra with this property. I think they must mean that the polyhedra need to be face-transitive, because, otherwise there's also the sandwich antiprism-bipyramid family shown by Ed Pegg.

Comment: @Rahul: Hmm, I managed to overlook that requirement.